# Return Peaks as a list

Tags: python, list, scipy

I have some code that identifies local maximum as peaks. I want to return the peaks as a list `[ 3,  6,  8, 10]`, but when it prints it comes back as `[ 3  6  8 10]` without the commas. How would I make peaks return as a list? Or is there a way to return it as a list from this function?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import uniform
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, argrelextrema
import pandas as pd


player_name = 'player'
game_log = [22.7, 16.7, 18.5, 38.2, 1.5, 8.6,
            12.6, 7.4, 34.5, 23.2, 34.5, 20.5, 24.0, 35.1]


rounded_game_log = [round(x) for x in game_log]
formatted_game_log = np.array(rounded_game_log)

y = formatted_game_log
y = np.array(y)
x = (range(0, (len(formatted_game_log))))
x = np.array(x)
colors = (0, 0, 0)
area = np.pi*3

dips = np.where((y[1:-1] < y[0:-2]) * (y[1:-1] < y[2:]))[0] + 1

plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+5, 1.0))
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y), max(y)+5, 5.0))
plt.axhline(y.mean(), color='k',
            linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.plot(x, y, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(y)
plt.plot(peaks, y[peaks], "x")
plt.plot(dips, y[dips], 'o')
plt.title(player_name)
plt.xlabel('Games')
plt.ylabel('Fantasy Points')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Simply convert the array to a list.  Please give it a try.  Also, post the *minimal* code needed to describe your problem.  Virtually none of the posted code deals with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
peaks = list(peaks)
print(peaks)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(peaks.tolist())
```